# ColdFusion createdate()

Tags: date, coldfusion

I am just learning about ColdFusion function `CreateDate`. But, when I use CreateDate the value output is different. I mean it changes month to day and day to month.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset txtBirthDate='07-10-1983'>
<cfset valueOf_txtBirthDate =  dateFormat(CreateDate(Year(txtBirthDate),Month(txtBirthDate),Day(txtBirthDate)),'YYYY-MMM-DD')>

#txtBirthDate#<br/><br/>
#valueOf_txtBirthDate#<br/>
</cfoutput>
```

The value of **txtBirthDate** is **07-10-1983**, but the value of  **valueOf_txtBirthDate** that `CreateDate` created is **1983-Jul-10**. Why is it July? It is supposed to be October: 07(date), 10(month), 1983(year).

Is there something wrong with the format?

Answer (score 7):

You are using `createDate()` in a very convoluted way. `txtBirthDate` isn't a date, so you shouldn't use it as an input for date functions like `year()`, `month()` etc. The input should *already* be a date object by the time you use a date function.

Let's say you start with the string `07-10-1983`, where the format is `mm-dd-yyyy`.

```
txtBirthDate ='07-10-1983'; // dd-mm-yyyy

// extract the specific date parts from the string
yyyy = listLast(txtBirthDate, "-");
mm = listGetAt(txtBirthDate, 2, "-"); 
dd = listFirst(txtBirthDate, "-");

// create a date object out of those components
birthDate = createDate(yyyy, mm, dd);

// output the date object in human readable format
writeOutput(dateFormat(birthDate, "YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

(obviously in real code you'd not have those comments which serve only to state the obvious!)

Only ever use `dateFormat()` at the last point as you output it. For other date operations, use the actual date object: `birthDate`.

Comment: Actually, ColdFusion will treat the string `07-10-1983` as a date since it is in a valid format for dates. Try running this code to verify: `writeDump( isDate( '07-10-1983' ) );` The problem is that ColdFusion is interpreting the date incorrectly  assuming the first part is the month when in fact it is the date. Hence why the OP states the month and date are incorrect. Your solution still works, but you need to swap out the logic for parsing the month and date, otherwise, he will still get the same date he was to begin with.

Comment: Good spot. Didn't notice he was working in dd-mm-yyyy. Just assumed he was working in your guys' lunatic format. I've adjusted my code accordingly. CF will take any old string and try to convert it into [whatever] to make it fit for a given function. But I suspect if you look under the hood if you give a date function a string, it will first attempt to cast that do a date, and use the date for the argument; rather than actually accepting a string where it expects a date. But, yes, a string formatted as `mm-dd-yyyy` will cast to a date nicely.

Comment: @ScottStroz it's bloody annoying, btw, that `isDate()` returns `Yes` (sic) for a string. It should return `No`. If the function was `canBeConvertedToDate()` then `Yes` might be a valid answer when it's passed a string (contigent on valid formatting, obviously). Still: it's been like that in CFML for a long time :-/

Comment: Not sure I agree there. It is a valid date. The problem is when the backwards date you guys use on your side of the pond has a first element that would be a valid date for the format we use over here. If it did not behave this way, parsing strings form form submissions and turning them into dates would be a pain in the ass.

Comment: Parsing dates from form submissions is worth the time and effort.  That time and effort can be reduced though with reuseable code.  Many years ago I wrote some custom tags that did some validation on date form fields.  Originally, they only returned strings, using dateformat().  I later modified them to return date objects as well.  My motivation was the observation that later versions of ColdFusion were less tolerent of imperfect coding than earlier versions.

Comment: *I suspect if you look under the hood .. it will first attempt to cast that do a date* Yep. As the docs indicate, it expects a date/time object. So if provided a string, CF will need to convert it first. Most, if not all, of the standard date functions, parse date strings "..according to the English (U.S.) locale conventions". To use different conventions, you must use the LS date functions. I have always thought date functions should have had an mask parameter, which would have avoided this kind of issue for numeric dates, but ... {shrug}.

Answer (score 1):

Because by default your date is mm/dd/yyyy format. So

```
<cfset txtBirthDate='07-10-1983'>
```

will be read as July 10th, 1983 by CF. Hence the outout...

Comment: More specifically, the date string will be *interpreted/parsed* per "English (U.S.) locale conventions", which means month first ie `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java function to perform this.
This is how it works:

```
<cfset txtBirthDate='07-10-1983' />
<cfset formatter = createObject("java","java.text.SimpleDateFormat") />
<cfset formatter.init("dd-MM-yyyy") />
<cfset birthDate= formatter.parse(txtBirthDate) />
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like should do the trick:

```
 <cfset txtBirthDate = '10-7-1983'>
 #DateFormat(txtBirthDate, "MMM, D, YYYY")#
```

notice i reversed the position of month and day in cfset to make it come out right.

Comment: Respectfully, this is not a good approach. The reason the string was interpreted as July 10, is because standard CF date functions *always* interpret strings according to U.S. conventions, ie month first. Reversing the month and day number to avoid using the function as designed is brittle at best. If you are working with "dd-mm-yyyy" strings, the proper approach is to use the LS (Locale sensitive) date functions with the appropriate Locale.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something simple like that :

```
txtBirthDate = '07-10-1983'; //dd-mm-yyyy
arrayDate = listToArray(txtBirthDate, '-');
date_birthDate = createDate(arrayDate[3], arrayDate[2], arrayDate[1]);

writeOutput(lsDateFormat(date_birthDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfscript>
    txtBirthDate=CreateODBCDate("1983-10-07");
    txtBirthDate=LSDateFormat(txtBirthDate, "dd/mm/yyyy");
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
    #txtBirthDate#
</cfoutput>
```